# Not clicking on the button even after using explicit wait

Tags: selenium

```
package seleniumTestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class ClassA {
    WebDriver driver;
    ChromeOptions options;
    WebDriverWait wait;

  @Test
  public void testClass() {
      wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
      WebElement tabX = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("---Xpath----")));
      tabX.click();

      WebElement btnY = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("---Xpath----")));
      btnY.click();
      System.out.println("btn Y clciked");

  }
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      String exePath = "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
      options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
      options.addArguments("20");
      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

      driver.get("---baseURL----");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();

      WebElement txtA = driver.findElement(By.id("---ID----"));
      WebElement txtB = driver.findElement(By.id("---ID----"));
      WebElement btnC = driver.findElement(By.id("---ID----"));

      txtA.sendKeys("xyz");
      txtB.sendKeys("zyx");
      btnC.click();

  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
  }

}
```

Error message displayed

```
FAILED: testClass
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: "xpath for btnY" (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: xpath for btnY']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Its executing

```
WebElement tabX = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("---Xpath----")));
          tabX.click();
```

Line but in AUT its not clicking on the mentioned tab. After this its going to next line

```
WebElement btnY = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("---Xpath----")));
          btnY.click();
```

As it has not clicked on tabX its not going to the page where btnY is present.But I am not sure why this is happening I am even using explicit wait for it to wait for tabX to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Error shows -

   > WebElement btnY = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("---Xpath----")));

after waiting 20 seconds it could not find the element.
So try the Xpath Helper on Chrome or similar to check the XPath is correct.

2. Maybe the element does not become visible - in that case you can use JavaScript code to click on it

   > JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
   >   javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);

Answer (score 0):

add Thread.sleep(15000) after btnC.click() in beforeTest() function to see script pass or not.

I guess after click the btnC, it trigger whole or part of page change. Even you wait tabX is display out before click on it.  But browser will failed to response to the click event in below two situiation:

1. the page still changing/loading when tabX.click()
2. the click envent of tabX is registered by javascript which executed at the last stage of page changing/loading procedure. So you can see the tabX is not means the click event had complete bind to tabX, if you click on it, no event to response.